# Recommended app for elaborating "System Charts" out of a Makefile in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, make, graphics, plotting

I'm looking for an application that is capable of plotting graphically as boxes on a chart (System Chart) all the components and operations of a `Makefile` so that the chart be taped prominently to the wall for easy reference during the development process.

I'm a Ubuntu user by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are these 2 Perl modules which look like they do what you're looking for:

- [Makefile::GraphViz](http://search.cpan.org/~agent/Makefile-GraphViz-0.18/lib/Makefile/GraphViz.pm)
- [GraphViz::Makefile](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/GraphViz-Makefile-1.15/Makefile.pm)

Yes they are named those names. There are examples on both those CPAN modules' reference pages that show how to do what you're asking. `Makefile::GraphViz` purports to make more sophisticated graphs than `GraphViz::Makefile`.

There is also a command line tool that comes with `Makefile::GraphViz` called `gvmake`  that you can use to generate graphs without writing any Perl programs.

For example:

```
$ gvmake
```

Will run the default target in your `Makefile`, typcically `all`, and output a `all.png` file.

Comment: @richardtk_1 - glad it solved you problem!